# Hibernate Batch Update

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jta, hibernate-entitymanager, batch-updates

I am trying to update a collection of a Java entity, but the order in which Hibernate executes the batch update leads to a constraint violation exception. 
I will use the following example to explain the situation.

Entity Student
Int id
String Name
String deskID

Rule: 2 students cannot have the same desk

1st transaction: Insert 2 students as follows
Student 1
Id:1
Name:ABC
DeskId:D1

Student 2
Id:2
Name:DEF
DeskId: D2

Now after this I decide to update both the student entities to swap their desks
and I send a collection of updated student entities to hibernate update
Student 1
Id:1
Name:ABC
DeskId:D2

Student 2
Id:2
Name:DEF
DeskId: D1

But this leads to constraint violation exception because i think the update is taking place one record at a time.

I am using JTA entity managers to manage the transactions. My code to update looks something like this

```
updateMultiple(Collection<Student> updatedStudents)
        for (final Student student: updatedStudents)
        {
            final Student st= this.entityManager.getReference(Student.class, Student.getId());
            student.merge(st);
        }
        this.entityManager.flush();
        return breakClauseDtos;
```

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is clear: The database checks the constraints when the SQL statement is executed and not at commit time. When executing the first SQL statement the constraint is violated.

You can go around the problem when you remove the desk from student 1 first, then assign it to student 2, then give student 1 his desc. This means three SQL statements (one more than necessary), and then perhaps you have to flush the session after every update (Hibernate reorders SQL statements, which can interfere with your manual order).

But the better solution is correcting the issue in your data model.

If every desk can be owned by only one student, then there is a n:1 relation from desk to student. Desk needs the id of the student as a foreign key. No extra constraint need to be defined. Now changing the desk means changing the student id in the desk record. This can be done with only two update statements.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually my data model is more complex than this. A good example to represent my issue would be..that a student has 2 properties Start Date and End date and i have a constraint on the DB saying that no 2 students should have overlapping Start and end date...That means we cannot have a student with start date:1 and  end date:4 and another student with start date:2 and end date:6